# What is the thickness of the mucous, submucosal, muscular and serous membranes of the stomach wall of a piglet aged 60-75 days? (Large White pig)

Tags: zoology, anatomy, animal-husbandry

There is publicly available data on the thickness of the layers of the stomach wall of piglets aged no more than 20 days. But at an early age, the thickness of the layers of the stomach wall increases extremely non-linearly and there is no way to predict how the layers will change by 60 days. Maybe there are specialists among the community who participated in the experimental determination of the thickness of the layers or those who have met studies on similar topics?
I will be glad of any constructive answers on the merits of the question. Thank you in advance for your response.
For those who are interested, I attach drawings with the dynamics of the thickness of the layers in the cardiac (a) and pyloric (b) parts of the stomach of piglets.[image]